# Need help identifying main processor for Roland synthesizer

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly, decompilation, firmware

I desperately need help figuring out the ic chips in this unit so I can view the firmware in ida pro.

So the unit is a roland gr-55 guitar synthesizer and i'm trying to disassemble the firmware into assembly language, but I have no info on the processor type. I have tried to analyze the firmware, which is a binary file using binwalk but wasn't able to find any info. I've also used the tool cpu_rec to see if it would give me any info and it told me it's a pic10 but I don't thinks that's accurate. I'll post pics below of the gr-55 motherboard, and the firmware , and some other stuff.

[R05011845 WSP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21XAj.jpg) IC

[R8A02021ABG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSmKJ.jpg)  IC

[MXIC mx29lv640ebti-70g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98xW7.jpg) IC

[ESMT m12l128168a-azl1p10jy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjjOD.jpg) IC

[gr-55 firmware link](https://www.roland.com/us/support/by_product/gr-55/updates_drivers/f64a41ce-c897-4fd5-94d7-71ec8ff6f036/) here's the roland gr-55's firmware

[gr-55 schematics](https://www.joness.com/gr300/service/GR-55_SERVICE_NOTES.pdf) here's the roland gr-55 schematics

I think the R8A02021ABG could be the main cpu due to these forms [(similar sythesizer internals)](http://forum.pianoworld.com/ubbthreads.php/topics/2385759/roland-bk-9-internals.html). This person seems to have some of the same ic numbers, and hes saying the R8A02021ABG is the main processor, and that it's a sh3/sh4 7700 series processor. When I go to the link for his units OS website 
[OS website for bk9](https://www.toppers.jp/fi4-kernel.html) it tells me that the processor for that OS is a sh3 (sh 7727). It seems that ida pro does not have an option for a (sh 7727). I read another form from someone who said they also have a (sh 7727) in their unit, this website wont let me post any more links so if you type mpc500 os code in google and click link for mpc-forms.com, it's on the second page second comment down. This person says they don't make a disassembler for the (sh 7727) and reverse engineering it would be impossible

My main goal is to be able to change some things in the roland gr-55's firmware, like changing some of the names to make things easier to understand so I can make music in peace. Is what i'm trying to do even possible or am I just giving myself a headache for no reason. Sorry if the post is confusing, and for the excessive links. If anybody can give me any info I would appreciate it.

Comment: schematics link goes to your local drive :)

Comment: The the firmware download EULA forbids reverse engineering, decompilation and disassembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The firmware is compressed, so it is no wonder that up to this point attempting to determine the target CPU of the firmware has been so troublesome.

[image: compressed firmware image]

A signature scan reveals a signature associated with LHA compression:

```
$ binwalk gr55.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4             0x4             LHa (2.x) archive data [lh5] [NSRL|LHA2]
```

[lhasa](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/lhasa.1.html) can be used to decompress the file, which produces a file called `appli.bin`. A signature scan of this file produces the following results:

```
$ binwalk appli.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2229080       0x220358        Ubiquiti partition header, header size: 56 bytes, name: "PARTITION#", base address: 0x00040000, data size: 524288 bytes
3513280       0x359BC0        Copyright string: "Copyright"
3527064       0x35D198        Broadcom 96345 firmware header, header size: 256, board id: "   1/8", ~CRC32 header checksum: 0x43452043, ~CRC32 data checksum: 0x43452042
3579113       0x369CE9        VxWorks symbol table, big endian, first entry: [type: uninitialized data, code address: 0xE00, symbol address: 0x13C18800]
7197404       0x6DD2DC        Copyright string: "Copyright Kobe Steel Ltd."
7252974       0x6EABEE        Copyright string: "Copyright 2004 TEPCO UQUEST, LTD."
```

Be aware that some may be false positives. For example, I believe that Broadcom 96345 firmware typically targets MIPS CPUs in routers. Further investigation is required. An entropy scan of `appli.bin` reveals that it is not compressed or encrypted:

[image: uncompressed]

There is quite a bit of string data in this binary, some of it potentially interesting. For example, this bit:

```
$Id: k_version.c,v 1.3 2010/09/22 13:10:33 shigeno Exp $
  SHELL for iTRON ver 1.01
===========================================================
  Copyright 2004 TEPCO UQUEST, LTD.
```

[Tepco Uquest](https://www.uquest.co.jp/en/) is a Japanese company that develops middleware for embedded devices.

A search for "SHELL for iTRON ver 1.01" results in this:

[image: dev presentation]

There is quite a bit of technical information contained in [this document](http://www.t-engine.org/wp-content/themes/wp.vicuna/pdf/specifications/en_US/MW_introduction_e_1.01.pdf); for example on page 71:

[image: doc page 71]

It may contain information relevant to identifying the CPU, as the SH (SuperH) family of CPUs is discussed ([Renesas SH7145](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/superh/sh7144/sh7144.html), SH7727).

Radare2 supports the SuperH instruction set.

Other strings include things like this:

```
St.Piano 3
St.Piano 4
St.Piano 5
Brite Piano
Stage Piano
Honky Tonk
LoFi Piano
Piano 1 w
European Pf
Piano 2 w
Honky-tonk
Honky-tonk w
Pop Piano 1
Pop Piano 2
Pop Piano 3
Piano 3 w
Stage EP 1
Stage EP 2
Stage EP Trm
Tremolo EP 1
E.Piano 1
```

Perhaps there is no need for reverse engineering, just patching strings.